# Как создать библиотеку на c++ и подключить её к проекту на c#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Добрый день.
Как создать библиотеку на c++
и подключить её к проекту на c#?

Хотя бы самый базовый пример.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Еще один вариант - использование c++/cli. Создается управляемый проект на плюсах, в нем создается несколько управляемых классов - которые потом используются в проекте на C#.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите здесь: https://drthitirat.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/combine-gui-of-c-with-c-codes/

Answer (score 1):

Точно вам не отвечу т.к. часто не использовал, но подскажу в какую сторону копать, а копать нужно в сторону PInvoke - пример использования внешнего API - http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CopyFile правда на английском, копирование файла с помощью библиотеки kernel32 встроенной в windows.

Аналогично будет с собственными библиотеками.