# Как совместить модули с разными ЯП?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, dll, модульность

Например:
На `c++` программа циклически считывает данные ожидая определенного события. Как только это событие произойдет должно высветиться окно для выбора дальнейших действий на `c#`. Экспортировать `c++` проект в `dll`? А какие еще способы есть?
P.s. конкретно в этом примере использования `c++` нужно для оптимизации работы с файлами, а `c#` для удобства проектирования оконного приложения.

Comment: а код на шарпе, который работает с файлом так медленный?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как создать библиотеку на c++ и подключить её к проекту на c#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/412593/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%91-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Answer (score 0):

Если ответить на поставленный вопрос, то тут есть несколько вариантов:
Managed C++ ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064103/interprocess-communication-between-c-sharp-and-c )
Всевозможные IPC/RPC

А вообще, я бы проверил скорость кода на C#